# IIS 8, New website from file..?

Tags: windows, iis

We're being forced by our ISP to migrate to Windows Server 2012. We have a couple dozen websites that need to be moved. Under IIS6 one could export a site to a text file and recreate the site, bindings, virtual directories, and all, on another server.

It looks in IIS8 that there's no way (that I can find, anyway) to similarly create a website - it looks like websites have to be created by hand. Please tell me I'm wrong..?

Comment: What version of IIS are you moving from?

Comment: IIS6. Hence the question about exporting->importing. Fingers still crossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Microsoft Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) tool.  It can export an IIS6 site into a "package" that can be imported into another IIS server.  Here's a walkthrough for migrating from IIS6 to IIS7+: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above